# Is it possible to use "The same git hub enterprise repo for different data factories "?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a dev datafactory named "adf-dev"
And another prod datafactory named "adf-prod"

And I have a single Github Enterprise account which has One repo named "adf-repo" which is having main,dev,uat branches .

can I connect adf-repo to the both datafactories ? and publish if I maintain different publish branches ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I connect adf-repo to the both datafactories ? and publish if I maintain different publish branches ?

Yes, you can connect 2 different data factories to the same repo in GitHub. And you can also have different publish branches for each of the data factories for the same repo. The following is the demonstration of the same. I have 2 data factories (one's factory environment is production and the other's is development) connected to same repo but different branches.

- For df060423
  [image]

- For df050423
  [image]

When I publish a sample pipeline to each of them, it has been successfully published as shown in the below images.

- For 060423
  [image]

- For df050423
  [image]